# Order_by BooleanField in views.py did not work. Python, Django

Tags: python, django, django-queryset

I try to return all fields which they have BooleanField 'True' in models.py. But I can not get it:

**My QuerySet (in views.py):**

```
prem_user = User.objects.all().order_by(premium=True)[4:8]
```

**This situation returns an error:**

```
order_by() got an unexpected keyword argument 'premium'
```

**models.py**

```
premium = models.BooleanField(default=False)
```

How can you return all 'BooleanField = True'? Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

```
 prem_user = User.objects.all().filter(premium=True)
```

Answer (score 1):

if you want to return only premium = True , then use filter option.